# SQL Server BCP: How to put quotes around all fields?

Tags: sql-server, csv, bcp

I have this BCP command:

```
'bcp DBName..vieter out c:\test003.txt -c -T /t"\",\"" -S SERVER'
```

The output CSV I get does not put quotes around the field names, instead it puts it around the commas! How can I get the `/t"\",\""` to put quotes around all fields.

Thanks all

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting the row terminator in addition to the field terminator should do the trick

```
'bcp DBName..vieter out c:\test003.txt -c -T -t"\",\"" -r"\"\n\"" -S SERVER'
```

This will likely work, but miss off the leading " for the first field of the first line, and perhaps the last field of the last line - I'm not sure, just guessing really, no server here!

or try using QUOTENAME to wrap text fields (you could also wrap numbers, but that isn't normally required.)

```
'bcp "SELECT id, age, QUOTENAME(name,'"') FROM DBName..vieter" queryout c:\test003.txt -c -T -t"," -S SERVER'
```

Comment: Is there ever a way to have the first and last have quotes - I really need a well formatted CSV file.

Comment: What you said happened - but the last fiedl had two quotes at the end and the first had no quotes. Do I just need to fiddle with the above to get what I want? Is there some docs I can look at as I haven't come across this regex stuff - if it is regex!

Comment: you could use `QUERYOUT` and then create a query using `QUOTENAME(column,'"')` for text fields.

Comment: Can I use QUOTENAME to quote all columns without passing the name of the column as I need to do this for different tables? I tried this but I got quite a few errors - is the quoting correct? I am using the above in `EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand`

Comment: You could potentially set @bcpCommand programmatically by querying syscolums and building the query, but it's getting very messy, not something i would want to do. This seems like a major problem with BCP!

Comment: Thanks Paul - I am not sure if I can go any further with this. Your answer is so close, but I can't believe I can't add a quote to the first field and remove one from the very last field of the last line! Damn it! Is it even possible?

Comment: Post-processing the generated file using your favorite script language should be able to do that...

Comment: Beware: [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) only supports input strings of length up to **128** characters, so it won't work for longer field values.

Comment: The solution with the quotes does answer the original question. But it does not escape the " characters with the field values. The QUOTENAME does, but as mentioned by Oliver, has a 128 bytes restriction. So both are not rock solid solutions

Answer (score 8):

You need to use CHAR(34) for the quote. This page has more details: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=153000

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you are fine for Powershell based script, you can try with below code, which does automatic quoting.

```bsh
Invoke-sqlcmd -ConnectionString "Server=SERVERNAME, `
3180;Database=DATABASENAME;Trusted_Connection=True;"  `
-Query "SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT * FROM TABLENAME" -MaxCharLength 700 | `
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -path C:\temp\FileName.csv -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bcp "SELECT char(34) + * +char(34) FROM atable queryout "C:\temp\out.csv" -T -N -c /t"\",\""
```

This will put quotes before and after each field (including the first and the last).

Comment: Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '*'.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the list of commands i used .

```
BCP "DECLARE @colnames VARCHAR(max);SELECT @colnames = COALESCE(@colnames + ',', '') + column_name from databaseName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='tableName'; select @colnames;" queryout "C:\HeadersOnly.csv" -r"\n\""  -c -T -Uusername -Ppassword -SserverName

bcp databaseName.schema.tableName out "C:\EmployeeDatawithoutheaders.csv" -T -t"\",\"" -r"\"\n\"" -c -Uusername -Ppassword -SserverName

copy /b C:\HeadersOnly.csv+C:\EmployeeDatawithoutheaders.csv C:\EmployeeData.csv

del C:\HeadersOnly.csv

del C:\EmployeeDatawithoutheaders.csv
```

Comment: Really like this solution, a few enhancements questions:
1. Any option to avoid the last row to be "
2. Any option to be smart and use the extra " only if the cells containing a column (,) or row (\n) delimiter inside?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your goal was to clearly seperate field values by using an unique identifier so that import procedure doesn't have an issue.

I had same issue and found this workaroud useful: Using an unusual field terminator, for example `|` or even a string `/#/` can be very unique and shouldn't mess with your string content. You also can HEX-Values (limited, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017)

**export**

```
bcp DB.dbo.Table out /tmp/output2.csv -c -t "/#/" -U sa -P secret -S localhost
```

**import**

```
bcp TargetTable in /tmp/output2.csv -t "/#/" -k -U sa -P secret -S localhost -d DBNAME -c -b 50000
```

Comment: I like this solution, but there is another situation in which this causes troubles. That is, if Carriage return/line feed are being used in the field values. The fields need to be enclosed to overcome that I think.

Answer (score 0):

The actual workable answer, that removes the leading quote, is to :

A) generate format file with bcp :

```
bcp db.schema.tabel format nul -c -x -f file.xml -t"\",\"" -r"\"\r\n" -T -k
```

B) edit that file to manually copy field 1 to field 0 above, as the first field, set Max_Length=1 and remove the separator and one quot the was in field1

```
<FIELD ID="0" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\&quot;" MAX_LENGTH="1" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
```

The trick works, as you are adding a field (interface to the file) to detect the first seprator, which results in an always null-value, but not add a row (interface for the query output).