# How to put quotes around all fields without specifying for the each individual field?

Tags: sql-server, csv, bcp

I wanted to export the data from the views to the CSV using the BCP Command, with each field of data in double quotes as text qualifiers,

For that, I have specified that in the XML format as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RECORD>
<FIELD ID="1" LENGTH="9"  xsi:type="CharFixed" />
<FIELD ID="2" LENGTH="3"  xsi:type="CharFixed" />
</RECORD>
  <ROW>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Id_ein_empr" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" LENGTH="9" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Emp_Loc_nbr" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" LENGTH="3" />
   </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

And I am using this XML format in BCP query as:

For that, I have written the following query.

```
DECLARE 
@DATACmd VARCHAR(500), 
@FileLocation varchar(255), 
@FileName varchar(255), 
@StateCode varchar(2), 
@v_Out_file_path varchar(255), 
@v_Data_path varchar(255),
@header_format_path varchar(255),
@v_Header_path varchar(255),
@HeaderFileName varchar(255);

SET @FileLocation ='c:\csv\output'
SET @FileName = 'Araddis_'+FORMAT(Getdate(), 'MMddyyyy') + '.txt'
SET @v_Out_file_path = 'c:\csv\' + @StateCode + '\output\' + 'Output_' + @FileName  
SET @v_Data_path = @FileLocation + '\' + @FileName


SELECT  @DATACmd = 'bcp '  
                        + '"select * from Db_1.dbo.[Forms]"'  
                        + ' queryout ' + @FileLocation   
                        + '\' + @FileName 
                        + ' -f "C:\csv\Format_FL.xml" -T -S' + @@servername;  
SELECT  @DATACmd AS 'Command to execute';
EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @DATACmd;
```

If there were just three columns on the records I would have done like
`SELECT id, age, QUOTENAME(name,'"') FROM DBName..vieter` as mentioned: [in the answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061113/sql-server-bcp-how-to-put-quotes-around-all-fields).

But I can't select the field one by one because it will have at least 50-60 fields in the export, without specifying the individual column?
Is there any way to add the quotes in the value, but ignore the null one?

Comment: The [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) doesn't allow it. The answer that you've linked is a hack that misses the opening quote on the first field and the closing quote on the last field, so is generating broken files by default. Have you considered other methods of generating CSV files, such as PowerShell's `Export-Csv` cmdlet?